# SPFx Document Search Result Add-in with ECB / CommandSet option

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

we are building SPFx based document listview based on search / user personalized view - my bookmarks or recent document;

We want to plug in OOTB ECB menu / command set; is there any option to integrate the same. Currently we are building our custom menu and all supported screens and updates.

Please guide us, thanks. Attached is capture 1 - OOTB menu which we want replicate in our SPFx Add-in;

Thanks in advance;

[image: OOTB Document action menu]

Comment: Any comments or more details required?

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to consume/re-use the OOB ECB menu in SPFx webparts.

You will have to build a custom one yourself preferably by using the Office UI Fabric React components e.g. the contextual menu https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/contextualmenu

Comment: Thanks, is there any way we can reuse the UI for actions like share, version etc.